# Get active PSTN caller id from Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, caller-id

I'm looking for a way to get the PSTN caller id / phone number of an active PSTN call in a tab or custom app in MS Teams. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried this [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-getpstncalls?view=graph-rest-beta)?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity Thank you for your reply. No, I didn't but as I understand it, it will give me historical data. What I look for, is to get the number of a current call, before the user even answered the call. End in mind is to look up information about the number in 3rd party systems.

Comment: One way i suggest is that you can try to have a bot add a PSTN participant to a meeting and see if it helps.

Comment: Does it helped?